# Website with function equivalents for various languages

Tags: programming-languages

When learning (or relearning) a language, a significant amount of time goes into learning the functions for doing basic operations. For example, suppose I want to reverse a String. In one language, it may be simple as `myString.reverse()`. In Python, it is `myString[::-1]`. In other languages, you may have to create an array, iterate through the string and add all the characters in reverse order and then convert it back to a string. What would be extremely useful would be a reference so that if you know the name of the function in one language, then I could find the equivalent in another. Googling or searching StackOverflow don't seem to solve this problem very well at the moment, as you have to usually try a large number of different queries. I guess I am thinking of some kind of Wiki system. Are there any websites that do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Main_Page). There is in fact a page on [reversing a string](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Reverse_a_string).

Comment: Now if only it had voting, reputation and badges